# CLI Perform Regex in Memory then feed to Command

Tags: command-line, regex, pandoc

I would like to use a `regular expression` to modify a file and then feed it to [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) in the `cli`.

Something like [this](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html):

```
perl -pe 's/_(.*)_/\\underline{$1}/g' source.md > pandoc -o source.pdf
```

So, I'm taking anything surrounded by `_` and replacing it with the Latex command `\underline{found text}` and then feed the result into the [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) command.

I thought I saw someone else do something like that but haven't been able to find it.

**Update:**

OS: `Lubuntu 13.04`

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: @terdon, You are right, I should have. It is now included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what pandoc is, but if it can read from STDIN (standard input) than you should be using pipe  `|`  and not `>` which outputs the result of perl command to pandoc file:

```
perl -pe 's/_(.*)_/\\underline{$1}/g' source.md | pandoc -o source.pdf
```